# ICE40 up5k Internal internal oscilator and ip's

Tags: yosys, ice40

i can see that icestorm support ice40 ultra plus up5k fpga, 
but this chip has internal osc, is there any example what i use it ? of course using yosys, icestorm (opensource)
and is there some examples where i  can use build in IP,s such as SPI, I2C, PWM ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i can see that icestorm support ice40 ultra plus up5k fpga

No, it does not. There has been [some preliminary work](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/icestorm/issues/68), but it is far from generating any up5k bit streams, with or without the internal oscillator. Only the devices listed on http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/ are supported (see table under the "What is the Status of the Project?" heading).